# how to rollback transaction in Apache Camel DSL?

Tags: java, transactions, apache-camel, spring-transactions

I wrote this code for education apache camel transaction

```
    from("jms:SAMPLE_1")
            .transacted()
            .log("message")
            .to("jms:SAMPLE_2")
            .to("jms:SAMPLE_3")
            .log("message")
            .process(exchange -> {
                throw new Exception();
            })
           .end();
```

I use transacted after an error occurs I have to trigger a transaction rollback, but for some reason the messages remain in the SAMPLE_2 and SAMPLE_3 queues. Why?
UPDATE:
I added bean

```
@Bean(name = "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
public SpringTransactionPolicy propogationRequired(PlatformTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager){
    SpringTransactionPolicy propagationRequired = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
    propagationRequired.setTransactionManager(jtaTransactionManager);
propagationRequired.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
    return propagationRequired;
}
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory cf) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(cf);
}
```

and fix route but this don't help me:

```
from("jms:SAMPLE_1")
            .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
            .log("message")
            .to("jms:SAMPLE_2")
            .to("jms:SAMPLE_3")
            .log("message")
            .process(exchange -> {
                throw new Exception();
            })
           .end();
```

I find in documentation this configuration

```
<blueprint ...>
<bean id="jmstx" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
</bean>
...
```

how to create bean's from this xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this does not work because the Camel JMS component does not know about your transaction manager etc.

As you already found out, the **component configuration is missing**.

I don't use plain JMS component but the specialized version for ActiveMQ but they are very similar. So I hope you can derive the missing bean from this one.

```
@Bean(name = "activemq") // bean name is used in URI activemq:...
public ActiveMQComponent createComponent(ConnectionFactory factory) {
    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    activeMQComponent.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
    activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);
    return activeMQComponent;
}
```

**Important**

As you see I don't set the transaction manager in the component. As long as you **just talk to 1 broker, you don't need the tx manager stuff** (you profit then from cache settings). To use transactions with your single broker

- Remove Spring transaction manager
- Remove Spring transaction policy
- Remove `transacted()` from Camel route

You just need to set `setTransacted(true)` and `setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false)` on the Camel JMS component and then all JMS consumers are transacted.

You can also find both setups [in the Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_enabling_transacted_consumption).